# Add plugins at ckeditor 4 in ASP.NET Core 5 MVC

Tags: audio, plugins, asp.net-core-mvc, ckeditor, mathtype

I try to to add 2 plugins (audio and Mathtype) in ASP.NET Core 5 MVC, but that doesn't work.

I installed ckeditor 4 from (https://ckeditor.com/cke4/builder) after build with plugins.

EXTRACTed folder and file as steps. The code is shown here:

```
<h2>Ckeditor</h2>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8"> 
    <title>CKEditor</title>
    <script src="~/Content/ckeditor/ckeditor.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <textarea name="editor1"></textarea>
    <script>CKEDITOR.replace('editor1');</script>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

In your HTML page add an element that CKEditor should replace:

```
<div id="editor">
    <p>This is some sample content.</p>
</div>
```

Two steps of creating a CKEditor 5:

1. Load the desired editor via the `<script>` tag.
2. Call the static `create()` method to create the editor.

> Example

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>CKEditor 5 – Classic editor</title>
    <script src="https://cdn.ckeditor.com/ckeditor5/26.0.0/classic/ckeditor.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <h1>Classic editor</h1>
    <div id="editor">
        <p>This is some sample content.</p>
    </div>
    <script>
        ClassicEditor
            .create( document.querySelector( '#editor' ) )
            .catch( error => {
                console.error( error );
            } );
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Result

[image]

Comment: I did same steps. but still not working when added plugins

Comment: Create a html file and copy the codes of Example , run again.